# How to hide clientside validation error message

Tags: 7, forms, javascript

Right now, I am using Clientside Validation. Everything works perfectly. But I would like to remove the error message which I set it showed at the top of the form. In the meantime, I would like to keep the error class which is added to my field input.

I have searched a lot about this but didn't get lucky. I know I might need to modify some code in **sites/all/modules/clientside_validation/clientside_validation.js** file, but I don't know which part I should touch.

Here is a sample screenshot:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: use `hook_form_alter` and create your own custom validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide error message using CSS or you can use [Inline Form Errors](https://www.drupal.org/project/ife) which allow you to hide the error message.

Comment: Eventually, I used js code cause that error message is controlled by js from the module. But using CSS is also working for hiding most of my form error message. Thank you very much~